# How do I create a puzzle piece in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I would like to paste a picture to a new blank picture with a puzzle shape on it so that I can create a puzzle piece, but I have forgotten how to do it.

I sort of remember that you will have to start a new file, put a puzzle shape on it, then click `Select All` on the picture and then `Copy` then bring it to the blank file with the puzzle shape on it and then `Paste`. I apologise for any inconvenience or stuffs, but the above step MUST be included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Clipping Masks` by placing the image ON TOP of the puzzle piece. It really makes no difference what document you do this in as far all the creating new documents you mention, just be careful not to save and that's irrelevant.

Step 1: Layer Placement

Puzzle Piece is UNDER photo (photo is currently turned off)

[image]

Photo turned on

[image]

Step 2: Right Click PHOTO layer and `Create Clipping Mask`

[image]

[image]

You can then adjust the individual layers without destroying your puzzle shape.

Comment: That's what I need. Thanks man. Just one more question, if I need to change the picture, do I just change it in the photo layer or do I start a new layer or are both OK?

Comment: To change entirely you'll probably put the new photo on a new layer and create clipping mask, but there's always lots of ways to do things depending on what your goal is. They're both certainly okay, just depends on what you want to achieve. @ArceusMaster0493